# Ubuntu/Drivers can damage the ethernet(RTL8111/8168/8411) card ? -happening with me

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, ethernet, motherboard

I've created ubuntu-14.04 image and restoring on disk and Motherboard model is GIGABYTE GA-H61M-WW with this Ethernet controller:

```
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

Now issue is that, as Ubuntu boots up, the link light will go off Ubuntu reports cable is disconnected and ethtool result:

```
Link Detection: no
```

For this, too many help over the internet and following many forums but not getting solution yet!

Main issue: After attached Ubuntu disk, then Switched back to windows 7 disk which was already worked Ethernet card but Now showing Ethernet unplugged !!!

So that reinstall drivers and boot with Linux Live OS but Ethernet not working..., I performed same on two same model PC's and facing same network card issues! So I don't want to performed on another PCs.

Everything are fine like cables, switchs and connectors...

My question is, in built Ethernet is physically failed by Ubuntu on both machine?

How can first solve this issue in windows 7 and after Ubuntu?

Comment: You might need to do a full power reset of your computer.  Unplug all power and remove battery (if it is a laptop).  With no power, press the power button a few times.  Then hook power back up and see if your network comes back up.  Fixed a problem I was having with my ethernet.

Comment: @Terrance Let I try but same problem in PCs !

Comment: You can do it on PC as well.

Comment: @Terrance Yes Fixed it the issue but after again boot ubuntu live and issue facing same ! "Link Detection: no" , Also try ubuntu 16.04 same issue, Can i say that ubuntu is not support it?  -Suck

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it could be incompatible.  Leave this question up, maybe someone else might have stumbled into this before.

Comment: Yep, It's a major bug in ubuntu 14.04/16.04 *#$%